# Django lambda function gives wrong results

Tags: django

I'm trying to get number of calculations per month in last 12 months in Django. I have function as follows:

```
def calculations_per_month_last_12_months(member_number):
    items = list(Calculations.objects
                 .filter(user__member__number=member_number)
                 .filter(price_date__gte=datetime.datetime.now().today() - relativedelta(months=12))
                 .annotate(month=TruncMonth('price_date'))
                 .values('month')
                 .annotate(total=Count('id'))
                 .values('month', 'total')
                 .order_by('month'))

    result = []
    for month in range(12):
        date = timezone.now() - relativedelta(months=month)

        month_results = list(filter(lambda i: date <= i['month'] < (date + relativedelta(months=1)), items))

        month_result = 0
        if month_results:
            month_result = month_results[0]['total']

        result.append({
            'month': date.strftime('%B'),
            'total_calculations': month_result
        })

    return result
```

In items I got what I want but the problem is in `for` loop. 
For example I get for **may** what needs to be for **june**.

The result that I get for one user is:

```
[{
    'month': 'June',
    'total_calculations': 0
}, {
    'month': 'May',
    'total_calculations': 1
}, {
    'month': 'April',
    'total_calculations': 4
}, {
    'month': 'March',
    'total_calculations': 0
}, {
    'month': 'February',
    'total_calculations': 0
}, {
    'month': 'January',
    'total_calculations': 0
}, {
    'month': 'December',
    'total_calculations': 0
}, {
    'month': 'November',
    'total_calculations': 0
}, {
    'month': 'October',
    'total_calculations': 0
}, {
    'month': 'September',
    'total_calculations': 0
}, {
    'month': 'August',
    'total_calculations': 0
}, {
    'month': 'July',
    'total_calculations': 0
}]
```

Thus, `total_calculations` for may should be `total_calculations` for june and so on..

The `price_date` in the database for that user is:

[image]

Thus, there is everything fine. 1 calculation in june and 4 in may.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Items:

```
[{
    'month': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo = < django.utils.timezone.LocalTimezone object at 0x10774fb00 > ),
    'total': 4
}, {
    'month': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo = < django.utils.timezone.LocalTimezone object at 0x10774fb00 > ),
    'total': 1
}]
```

Comment: This sort of problem can only be sorted by debugging. For example to figure out what your lambda does, we need to know what your `items` contains but how?

Comment: @e4c5 I updated my question.

Comment: thank you for doing so. Even then it takes a lot of mental arithmatic for someone to figure this out. Can I please suggest that you install an interactive debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it adding one month `i['date'] + relativedelta(months=1)`, that is probably not ideal but it works.

Thus, instead of:

```
month_results = list(filter(lambda i: date <= i['date'] < (date + relativedelta(months=1)), items))
```

now I have :

```
month_results = list(filter(lambda i: date <= i['date'] + relativedelta(months=1) < (date + relativedelta(months=1)), items))
```